# VB.net - Issues with reading radio buttons between forms

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I have a basic math test program, and 2 forms to allow the user to choose which function to test on.

The first form has a list of radio buttons with the 4 basic math functions and a button to load the next form.
The second form contains this code on Load...

```
    'Change function sign to reflect chosen option
    If frmOptions.rdoAdd.Checked Then
        lblFunc.Text = "+"
    ElseIf frmOptions.rdoSub.Checked Then
        lblFunc.Text = "-"
    ElseIf frmOptions.rdoMult.Checked Then
        lblFunc.Text = "x"
    ElseIf frmOptions.rdoDiv.Checked Then
        lblFunc.Text = "÷"
    End If
```

If I change the Checked field in the properties in form 1, it passes to form 2.
However if I use the radio buttons to choose a different option, form 2 sticks with the default choice from form 1.

**EDIT**

Changed a few lines based from input, but still having this issue.
I'll run through it again.

1. frmOptions has 4 radio buttons, addition is default chosen.
2. After selecting one, the user clicks a button to open frmTest.
3. The above code runs upon first load to change a label to reflect what was chosen on frmOption above.

On step 3, the label on frmTest that is supposed to be changed based on the Checked radio button from frmOption never changes. It doesn't even change on the first load of the form, so I think something is wrong with the Checked property of the radio buttons.

Hopefully this clears things up a bit.

Comment: What do you mean by "However if I use the radio buttons to choose a different option, form 2 sticks with the default choice from form 1" Do you mean after form 2 has loaded?

Comment: I choose from one of 4 options on form1, click a button that hides form1 and opens form2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's not enough information here to know for sure.

It sounds like your first form is loading the second form with values the first time, but then on subsequent calls it doesn't load the second form because it's already loaded.  Does that sound correct?

If so, then that you are probably setting values on the first form which get passed to the second form.  Instead, create properties on the second form and load it first.  Then have the first form manipulate those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try firing an event when the radio button changes instead of when form2 loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Form2.Shown` event instead of `Form2.Load`.

A form is loaded only once, but it can be shown numerous times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
If My.Forms.Form1.Radiobutton_Name.Checked = True Then
    lblFunc.Text = "+"
ElseIf My.Forms.Form1.Radiobutton_Name.Checked = True Then
    lblFunc.Text = "-"
ElseIf My.Forms.Form1.Radiobutton_Name.Checked = True Then
    lblFunc.Text = "x"
ElseIf My.Forms.Form1.Radiobutton_Name.Checked = True Then
    lblFunc.Text = "÷"
End If
```

Comment: Try to not add any code corresponding to the radiobuttons in form 2 Load event. That could be why the labels aren't changing.